# How to poll mouse macro keys without third party software?

Tags: c++, c, windows, mouseevent, mouse

Lets say we've got a Gaming MMO-mouse that has 12 keys at the side.

I researched a bit and found out that Windows doesnt really support so many keys so you'd have to use the mouse driver to access the keys. What I didnt find is, **how** do you access the keys **with** the driver?

All these mice have their respective software that lets you rebind them but whats interesting to me is how that looks like on a lower level **without** the software.

- How do I poll for the pressed macro keys in my own c++ program?
- How do we exchange information with the driver?

Comment: E.g. If you remap a certain mice key to be F11, you can look if F11 is pressed.

Comment: If the mouse need a specific software to be configurated, probably there is a specific DLL that do the magic: it makes you able to communicate with the mice device.

Comment: @LPs yes, I found some DLLs but how do I listen to the driver? How does the communication work?

Comment: If you haven't got documentation about DLL functions and how they work you could try to use app that can analyze DLLs. Something like [THIS](http://www.alternate-tools.com/pages/c_dllanalyzer.php?lang=ENG). Once you have got a list of functions you could try to understand how do they work.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest, write a small program that polls the USB port where the mouse is connected,

each time it receives data from the mouse, display that data.

Keep track of the correlation between which mouse action you made and the resulting input from the mouse.

Comment: In theory this sounds great. Have you got an example? I've been fighting through the WINAPI with no luck.

Comment: I have seen, on stackoverflow, examples of how to talk to the USB ports under windows.  Suggest a search of stackoverflow